# What's the most idiomatic way to express an iterable of a single element in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections, option-type

So far when I need to pass around an `Iterable` that consists of just one element, I pass a `Some` value; but that requires an implicit conversion.

In Java I would use `java.util.Collections.singleton`, and I guess there's something equivalent in Scala that better fits this use case.

Comment: An `Option[T]` can be made iterable without implicit conversion (e.g. `.toList`). There is nothing wrong with using `List(single)` either.

Comment: I'm doing that a few billion times, so I thought that it wouldn't hurt to use an implementation that is the most lightweight (although my feeling is that the JIT could probably inline that easily)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look to the implementation of the `apply` methods (constructors) of the collections (`Iterable`, `Seq`, `List`) that could fit the bill, they take varargs which require extra wrapping the object in an array and then looping over it or calling another method.

So I think I'm going to stick with *consing* the object like `x :: Nil`; that looks like the most lightweight way to achieve it and it's explicit that you are making a collection.

Comment: The varargs wrapping is just machinery. IMHO, you can't second-guess language machinery. If you can't add `f(x: X)` to `f(xs: Iterable[X])`, maybe an implicit wrapper. That avoids an extra wrapper and also the extra syntax. Maybe you can scope the implicit appropriately.

Comment: Possibly GenericCompanion should have an apply that takes one element and another that takes two or more, as other API do.

Comment: So the answer on gitter is that overloading is evil, which we knew already.

Answer (score 3):

`Iterable(x)`, just as to get a `Seq` of a single element you write `Seq(x)`, `List(x)`, etc.